# running a PCA on a RasterStack in R

Tags: r, raster, spatial, pca

I am attempting to run a PCA on a set of the variables available in Bioclim. I noted that rasterPCA() is no longer available in R as its package has been discontinued, and it looks like that is because some issues with that package were not resolved. Below, I attempted to run a PCA on the RasterStack directly (this is necessary in this case, because if I convert to a data frame I will lose the spatial information about each row, and my goal is to create a new rasterstack with all of the PCs that this PCA will generate).

```
#Libraries:

library(geodata)
library(raster)

#Downloading the data:

bioclim_all <- worldclim_global(var = "bio", 
                                res = 0.5, 
                                path = "/data")

#Creating a bounding box:

bounding_box <- extent(x = c(-118.2724, -86.4236, 14.3237, 32.4306))

#Cropping to a smaller resolution:

crop_bioclim <- crop(x = bioclim_all, y = bounding_box)

#Conduct a PCA with standardization:

pca <- prcomp(crop_bioclim, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in svd(x, nu = 0, nv = k) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Does anyone know how to make this direct PCA analysis work, in a similar vein to how rasterPCA used to work? Or a way of preserving spatial data when running the PCA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using "terra", the replacement of "raster".
You can directly use `prcomp` or `princomp` with a SpatRaster.

Example data (always include some when asking an R question)

```
library(terra)
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
```

Solution:

```
pca <- prcomp(logo)

pca
#Standard deviations (1, .., p=3):
#[1] 124.814772  17.084151   1.456423
#
#Rotation (n x k) = (3 x 3):
#             PC1        PC2        PC3
#red   -0.5935507  0.5073220 -0.6247575
#green -0.5846008  0.2617406  0.7679412
#blue  -0.5531179 -0.8210458 -0.1412245
```

Now you can use `predict` to map the principal components:

```
x <- predict(logo, pca)
plot(x)
```

[image]

If you have a very large raster you can use `princomp` instead or take a sample of the cells. For example

```
pca <- prcomp(logo, maxcell=100000)
```

To make a SpatRaster from your RasterStack `s` you can do  `r <- rast(s)` and to go the other way you can do `ss <- stack(r)`

Comment: The issue I'm having is this process doesn't work on RasterStack objects. I still need to figure out how to run this on a RasterStack, because each layer of the RasterStack contains a variable that goes into the PCA. rasterPCA() was designed to do this, and I'm looking basically for a replacement for that. See tutorial: http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/rasterPCA.html

Comment: Then just make a SpatRaster from your RasterStack  with `x <- rast(s)`

Comment: Your spatSample() snippet, present before the latest edit, was very helpful to me. Could you clarify why you decided to remove it?

Comment: This is because things changes a bit in terra 1.7-71. You can now use `princomp` with any size raster, or use the "maxcell" argument for sampling.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. The solution came in two parts. One, I found a replacement for rasterPCA() in the form of raster_pca() [(package 'synoptReg')](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/synoptReg/html/raster_pca.html). However, it would still give me the following error:

```
# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster"’
```

It looks like PCA functions just don't work with the SpatRaster objects, but they will work with RasterStack objects (maybe someone else can explain why this is the case).

Getting your Worldclim data with worldclim_global() will create a SpatRaster, as will rast().

It's a bit of extra work to make a plain old RasterStack, but this code is functional for me:

```
library(terra)

bio1<-raster('C:/.../wc2.1_2.5m/wc2.1_2.5m_bio_1.tif')
bio2<-raster('C:/.../wc2.1_2.5m/wc2.1_2.5m_bio_2.tif')
bio3<-raster('C:/.../wc2.1_2.5m/wc2.1_2.5m_bio_3.tif')
bio4<-raster('C:/.../wc2.1_2.5m/wc2.1_2.5m_bio_4.tif')

biostack<-stack(bio1,bio2,bio3,bio4)

# pca1<-prcomp(biostack)
## Gives: Error in svd(x, nu = 0, nv = k) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
## clearly base R stats is just useless for this

#install.packages('synoptReg')
library(synoptReg)# raster_pca function

pca1<-raster_pca(biostack,aggregate=0,focal=0)

pca1

# $rasterPCA
# class      : RasterStack 
# dimensions : 4320, 8640, 37324800, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
# extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# names      :       PC1,       PC2,       PC3,       PC4 
# min values : -2.656944, -4.054211, -2.162238, -2.014184 
# max values :  3.999249,  3.174859,  2.088713,  0.939421 
# $summary
#                  Comp.1    Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4
# sdev          1.6386658 0.9594545 0.54523932 0.31134434
# prop.variance 0.6713064 0.2301383 0.07432148 0.02423382
# cum.variance  0.6713064 0.9014447 0.97576618 1.00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a while ago and I wrote some functions for this task (and for large raster, one function breaks stack of large raster into chunks, perform PCA on each chunk and merge them together at the end).
Maybe this can help you.

The PCA model I used is the one provided by CARET.

Packages:

```
library("sp")
library('sf')
library("raster")
library("dismo")
library("knitr")
library("rprojroot")
library("caret")
library("Metrics")
```

The trained PCA model is provided by CARET, processed in one line:

```
  # principal component analysis (PCA)
  pp_pca <- preProcess(combine_input_data_filtered, method = c("pca"))
```

You can use any trained PCA model (in CARET's format) to produce PCA rasters (saved to .tif files) from a raster stack, providing the PCA model is trained with variables with the same names as the rasters in the raster stack. Here is the code:

```
process_spatial_chunk <- function(chunk, pca_model) {
  # chunk: the raster layer to be processed
  # pca_model: the trained pca_model generated by the Caret package. For the training, please refer to prepare_input_data_kfold_pca
  # Assuming 'chunk' is a raster stack with all layers but a subset of the area
  pca_result <- predict(pca_model, newdata = na.omit(raster::values(chunk)))
  
  pca_raster_list <- list()
  for (i in 1:8){
    this_pcra <- chunk[[1]]
    this_pcra[!is.na(raster::values(chunk))] <- pca_result[, i]
    print(this_pcra)
    pca_raster_list[[i]] <- this_pcra
  }
  return(pca_raster_list)
}



# Main function to process the raster stack in spatial chunks. Divide raster into chunks, vectorize, PCA, rasterized, merge chunks together, and save to dir

process_raster_spatially <- function(raster_stack_path, pca_model, clim_type_name,num_chunks=40) {
  # raster_stack_path: the path to a directory under which all the files with .tif ending will be read as input raster and stack into a raster stack.
  # pca_model: the trained pca_model generated by the Caret package. For the training, please refer to prepare_input_data_kfold_pca
  # clim_type_name: the name of the directory to save the PCA raster layers under.
  # num_chunks=40: the number of small chunks to break the large raster layer into. As an example, for a raster layer covering the whole north america with 1km resolution, divide it into 40 chunks will ensure the PCA performs well.
  cat("start raster pca for all input data...")
  startTime <- Sys.time()
  processed_stack <- list()
  # process raster
  this_raster_stack_list <- list.files(raster_stack_path, pattern = '.tif$', full.names = T) 
  raster_stack <- raster::stack(this_raster_stack_list)
  this_raster_subset <- raster::subset(this_clim,names(pca_model$mean)) # not all the input variables are used to calculate PCA
  extent_raster <- extent(this_raster_subset)
  # crop the raster extent
  extent_raster@xmax <--40 #MODIFYEXTENT
  print(extent_raster)
  
  # Divide the extent into spatial chunks
  chunk_width <- (extent_raster@xmax - extent_raster@xmin) / num_chunks
  
  for (i in 1:40) {
    cat("\n",i)
    xmin_chunk <- extent_raster@xmin + (i - 1) * chunk_width
    xmax_chunk <- xmin_chunk + chunk_width
    chunk_extent <- extent(xmin_chunk, xmax_chunk, extent_raster@ymin, extent_raster@ymax)
    cat("\n crop")
    chunk <- crop(raster_stack, chunk_extent)
    this_raster_pca <- process_spatial_chunk(chunk, pca_model)
    print(this_raster_pca)
    processed_stack[[i]] <- this_raster_pca
  }
  
  # Combine processed chunks
  cat("\n merge")
  save_this_raster_pca_dir <- paste(all_path_stack$maxent_model_dir,"/",clim_type_name,sep = "")
  if (!dir.exists(save_this_raster_pca_dir)){
    dir.create(save_this_raster_pca_dir)
  }else{
    print("dir exists")
  }
  for (i in 1:8){
    raster_pci_list <-lapply(processed_stack, '[[', i)
    final_raster_pci <- do.call(merge,raster_pci_list)
    this_pca_save_path <- paste(save_this_raster_pca_dir,"/","PC",i,".tif",sep = "")
    cat(this_pca_save_path)
    raster::writeRaster(final_raster_pci, this_pca_save_path, format = "GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
  }
  # end of testing
  endTime <- Sys.time()
  print(endTime-startTime)
  cat("finish pca")
  
}
```

Full demo here:
https://github.com/largeseabass/R_GIS_toolkit/tree/main

Comment: Hi Seabass, welcome to SO. While your link may solve the OP's question, link-only answer are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained. Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35628440)

Answer (score 0):

The `crop_bioclim` is probably not the accepted format for `prcomp()` function. Try to first convert it to a `data frame object` and perform `pca`:

```
...
crop_bioclim <- crop(x = bioclim_all, y = bounding_box)

# convert to data frame
crop_bioclim_df <- as.data.frame(crop_bioclim)

#Conduct a PCA with standardization:
pca <- prcomp(crop_bioclim_df, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this process is problematic for this specific circumstance because converting to a dataframe removes the spatial features of the initial raster, which I need to preserve.